# Return all primary keys affected by update query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Is it possible to retrieve all the primary keys affected by an update query? Ex:

Table:

```
+-------------+---------+--------+
|idx (PK, int)|FirstName|LastName|
+-------------+---------+--------+
|1            |Jane     |Smith   |
+-------------+---------+--------+
|2            |John     |Test    |
+-------------+---------+--------+
|3            |Adam     |Smith   |
+-------------+---------+--------+
```

Query:

```
UPDATE clients SET [LastName] = 'Smith' WHERE [FirstName] = 'John'
```

What i want returned:

> 2

But i also want this method to work for multiple rows... Ex:

Query:

```
UPDATE clients SET [FirstName] = 'test' WHERE [LastName] = 'Smith'
```

What i want returned:

> 1, 3

Comment: SQL Server implements [`OUTPUT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause in `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: As noted by PM 77-1: You can use an `OUTPUT` clause to get any data from the rows (Note plural.), e.g. `Id` values.  `OUTPUT` can be used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` and provides access to both before and after values in the case of `UPDATE`.  A tool well worth having in your pocket.

Answer (score 9):

Use the OUTPUT clause in conjunction with a table variable to get *all* IDs updated:

```
declare @insertedIds table (id int)

update
  supportContacts
set
  type = 'Email, updated'
output inserted.id into @insertedIds
where
  type = 'Email'

select id from @insertedIds
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a transaction that:

1. selects your records into a temp table
2. updates the main table
3. selects from the temp table

Answer (score 0):

Use the [OUTPUT clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

```
UPDATE clients SET [FirstName] = 'test' OUTPUT inserted.idx WHERE [LastName] = 'Smith'
```

Answer (score 0):

The [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28OUTPUT_TSQL%29;k%28SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1%29;k%28SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1%29;k%28MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT%29;k%28DevLang-TSQL%29&rd=true) clause should do what you want.

```
UPDATE clients SET [LastName] = 'Smith' OUTPUT inserted.idx WHERE [FirstName] = 'John' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like using OUTPUT is the way to go.
Check out this fiddle I Created

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2c3aa1/10